# CAKeyframeAnimation different on device / simulator

Tags: ios, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

So I am using a `CAKeyframeAnimation` to spin a layer 360*s. It works as intended on iPhone 6 and iOS Simulator:

http://www.goloskok.com/u/cap_2016-12-02_12-51-28_pm.mov

but looks different on iPad mini 1st Gen:

http://goloskok.com/u/ipad-C97WYOhVhj.mov

I suspect that this has something to do with iPad mini being 32bit?

The code I'm using is:

```
[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:RTSpinKit3DRotationWithPerspective(1.0/120.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)],
[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:RTSpinKit3DRotationWithPerspective(1.0/120.0, 0.5 * M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)],
[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:RTSpinKit3DRotationWithPerspective(1.0/120.0, M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)],
[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:RTSpinKit3DRotationWithPerspective(1.0/120.0, 2 * M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)],
[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:RTSpinKit3DRotationWithPerspective(1.0/120.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)]
```

With the used function being:

```
CATransform3D RTSpinKit3DRotationWithPerspective(CGFloat perspective, CGFloat angle, CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat z) {
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = perspective;
    return CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: I have found a couple of system bugs related to 32 vs 64 bit, but only a couple. Are both devices running the same OS version? It seems more Kelly that it's a difference between OS versions.

Comment: @DuncanC They are running same OS versions, so not that..